# How to know "topic" name from Firebase notification on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-notifications

I'm trying to use Firebase in my iOS application. I successfully integrated it and receiving notifications from all 3 Targets (user segment, topic and single device). **My question is how to know a particular notification is received from which topic?**

I'm following this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/topic-messaging) and this [github page](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/messaging)

EDIT:

I'm testing on iOS11.2 (XCode9.2) & my response (userInfo) is:

```
{
    aps =     {
        alert = test;
        sound = default;
    };
    "gcm.message_id" = "0:1513282329413512%38894e8e28894e8e";
    "gcm.n.e" = 1;
    "gcm.notification.sound2" = default;
    "google.c.a.c_id" = 1542306492273623048;
    "google.c.a.c_l" = test;
    "google.c.a.e" = 1;
    "google.c.a.ts" = 1513182256;
    "google.c.a.udt" = 0;
}
```

I'm getting `gcm.message_id` but it looks like `"gcm.message_id" = "0:1512894251264950%38894e8e38894e8e";` **How to map this to my topic name?**

Thanks.

Comment: the user subscribes to the topic, when you send a notification using that topic then it means that the person who subscribed to that topic has recieved it

Comment: Yes. For e.g: I've subscribed to 10 topics. How to know out of those 10 topics, I received notification for which one?

Comment: how are u sending the notification from console?

Comment: By selecting a topic. I'm receiving that notification also, just can't check the topic name in AppDelegate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer from Firebase support team.

> It doesn't seem like there's a way to get this info as per
>   documentation. One workaround I can think of is if you would pass the
>   topic name in your data payload, you can then manually handle it from
>   your code and map it to your message_id.

So looks like this works on Android but on iOS it's not supported today (Dec 2017)